# Explicit type parameter

Tags: java, generics

Reading `Java Generics and Collections` book.

```
//given
public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dst, List<? extends T> src) {
  ....
}
```

Now, it says - `We could also declare the above method with several possible signatures.`

```
public static <T> void copy(List<T> dst, List<T> src)                    1
public static <T> void copy(List<T> dst, List<? extends T> src)          2  
public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dst, List<T> src)            3
public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dst, List<? extends T> src)  4
```

The first of these is too restrictive, as it only permits calls when the destination and source have exactly the same type(`understood`).

The remaining three are equivalent for calls that use implicit type parameters (`understood` - type inference algo will infer the appropriate type),

`Confusing part -`
but differ for explicit type parameters.
For the example calls above, the second signature works only when the type parameter is `Object`, the third signature works only when the type parameter is `Integer`.

Am confused because of what I tried (below)

```
public class AsList {
    public static void main (String...a) {
        List<Number> l4 = new ArrayList<Number>();
        List<Object> l5 = new ArrayList<Object>();
        List<Integer> l6 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        //type is inferred implicitly for the below call
        copy(l4, Arrays.<Integer>asList(1, 2, 3));

        //type is specified explicitly
        AsList.<Number>copy(l4, Arrays.<Integer>asList(1, 2, 3));   \\why?  5
        AsList.<Object>copy(l5, Arrays.<Integer>asList(1, 2, 3));           6
        AsList.<Integer>copy(l6, Arrays.<Integer>asList(1, 2, 3));  \\why?  7
    }
    public static <T> void copy(List<T> dst, List<? extends T> src) {
        for (int i = 0; i < src.size(); i++) {
            dst.add(src.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Here, as per the `Confusing part` only statement `6` should have executed but `5` & `7` are also working. Why?

**Edit**
Example calls mentioned in the `Confusing part` are as below

```
Collections.copy(objs, ints);
Collections.<Object>copy(objs, ints);
Collections.<Number>copy(objs, ints);
Collections.<Integer>copy(objs, ints);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case 5 the formal parameters are `List<Number>` and `List<? extends Number>`. Passing in a `List<Number>` and a `List<Integer>` is perfectly ok.

In case 7 the formal parameters are `List<Integer>` and `List<? extends Integer>`. Again passing in `List<Integer>` and `List<Integer>` is fine.

Comment: I also think the same but then what I don't understand is the statement - `the second signature works only when the type parameter is Object` mentioned by the author for case `2` in the `confusing part`.

Comment: What are the "example calls above" referenced in case 2?

Comment: Ok. I understand it now. Author is saying that from the calls shown case 2 will only work for the call where the explicit type specified is `Object`. Correct?